# neural net - undefined column selected

Tags: r, neural-network

## Data Partition

I have several factor variables so I decided to use dummy variables instead for ANN.

```
set.seed(222)
m <- model.matrix( ~price+month+year+area+larea+otype+cid+rid+did+renovation+nrooms+nbeds+nbaths+nbalcs+wfloor+status, data = data)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(m), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
training <- m[ind==1,]
testing <- m[ind==2,]
```

## neural net

```
n <- neuralnet(price~.,
                data = training,
                hidden = 1,
                err.fct = "sse",
                linear.output = FALSE)
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : 
>     undefined columns selected

I use dot because I have 94 explanatory variables. when I run price on two explanatory variables to see what the problem was it worked. There is some problem with dot, is it only used for linear regression and I got it wrong? how can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you please check whether `price` is one of the column names in 'm'..  Without a small reproducible example, it is difficult to know what happened

Comment: I have already checked and this is the exact name, with small p etc. I think there is something wrong with dot.

Comment: I typed it, I edited my post if it helps.

Comment: What is `data` in the post.  WIthout that, we get error

Comment: at first the data name was "data", then when I use dummy variables it is called m, but for ann I need test and training data therefore, for neural net I use training data.

Comment: I can't reproduce with `data(iris);nn <- neuralnet(Species~ ., iris, linear.output = FALSE, hidden = 1, err.fct = "sse")`

Comment: okay, now got the idea, `m` is a `matrix` and not a data.frame.  according to `?neuralnet` `data - a data frame containing the variables specified in formula.`

Comment: ~~~
library(neuralnet)
set.seed(333)
m<-as.data.frame(m)
training<-as.data.frame(training)
testing<-as.data.frame(testing)
n <- neuralnet(price ~ ., 
               data = training,
               hidden = 1,
               err.fct = "ce",
               linear.output = FALSE)
~~~

Comment: Please check the `colnames(m)`, `colnames(training)` i think it got changed after the model.matrx

Comment: > colnames(training)
 [1] "(Intercept)"                     "price"                          
 [3] "month"                           "year"  

this is first two lines, it did not change.

Comment: it would be better if you create an example of 'data' so that I can test it. thanks

Comment: I can send you sample of the data if it is possible, because creating an example of data might be misleading in this case

Comment: can you pllease check my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `model.matrix` is a `matrix` and not a `data.frame`.  According to `?neuralnet`

> data - a data frame containing the variables specified in formula.

---

So, we may need to convert to data.frame with `as.data.frame` as this works correctly with `data.frame` input

```
library(neuralnet)
data(iris)
nn <- neuralnet(Species~ ., iris, 
        linear.output = FALSE, hidden = 1, err.fct = "sse")
nn$weights
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#           [,1]
#[1,]  -9.900398
#[2,]  -1.527258
#[3,] -13.201669
#[4,]  11.624309
#[5,]  17.896367

#[[1]][[2]]
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,]  32.51005 -4.014045 -4.303671
#[2,] -65.72300  4.013259  4.304652
```

---

In the OP's code, the issue is that `model.matrix` creates column names with nonstandard names.  It can be converted to standard names with `make.unique`

```
names(training) <- make.names(names(training))
n <- neuralnet(price ~ ., 
            data = training,
            hidden = 1,
            err.fct = "sse", 
      linear.output = FALSE)



n$weights
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#              [,1]
# [1,]  -0.62625018
# [2,]   1.39124245
# [3,]  -2.59472834
# [4,]   0.27773897
# [5,]   7.15830865
# [6,]  -2.93583230
# ...
```

Comment: I have already convert matrix to data frame bus still did not work. Is there any other way I can use?

Comment: @JuliAvlokhashvili when you convert the model.matrix to data.frame, please check the column names because if I am not mistaken, it adds a prefix

Comment: @JuliAvlokhashvili the column names would be changed i.e. `colnames(model.matrix(~ Species -1, iris))#
[1] "Speciessetosa"     "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica" `