# How to resolve error in R neuralnet function- undefined columns selected?

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm getting the following on running the neuralnet function:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

The code I used is as shown below:

```
 #creating training and test dataset
it_trainann<-norm_it_1h[1:1748, ]
it_testann<-norm_it_1h[1749:2185, ]
sum(is.na(it_trainann))
[1] 0
sum(is.na(it_testann))
[1] 0
#prediction using ANN
library(neuralnet)
it_model<-neuralnet(Unit.Price~., data=it_trainann, hidden=3)
```

norm_it_1h is a data frame composed of normalised numerical variables.
I could neither find NA values nor non-numeric variables.
On tracing back, I got the following result:

```
6: stop("undefined columns selected")
5: `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables)
4: data[, model.list$variables]
3: as.matrix(data[, model.list$variables])
2: cbind(intercept = 1, as.matrix(data[, model.list$variables]))
1: neuralnet(Unit.Price ~ ., data = it_trainann, hidden = 3)
```

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check that the exact name of the variable in it_trainann is `Unit.Price`?

Comment: @G5W, Yes I did

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while working on big data. I tried some solutions in StackOverflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239006/neural-net-undefined-column-selected) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568073/why-am-i-getting-error-in-data-framedata-model-listvariables-undefin) but none of them solved my issue. Then, I printed all variable names that I've used on my model. I noticed that some of my variable names have special strings.
In sum, changing col names that seems to problematic fixed my error:

```
colnames(mydataframe)[which(names(mydataframe) == "A problematic name $½£ _")] <- "NotProblematicName"
```